# Как перевести строки из статической страницы темы WP?

Tags: wordpress, polylang

Столкнулся с потребностью влезть в WP. Я как человек, который не сталкивался с кастомизацией тем,Ю не могу понять. Я использую плагин Polylang для переводов. С ними и проблема. Статическая главная страница подтягивается из темы, я ее немного переделал. Но. Каким образом я могу изменить переводы по переключении языка из виджета и могу ли вообще? Как перевести меню ясно. Можно ли при переключении языка отправлять на уже переведенную страницу или любым обрразом перевести весь текст на нужный язык по переключению без автоперевода?
Для ясности: понимаю в программировании, функциях и прочем. Не пользуюсь php и WP.

Answer (score 0):

Для перевода строк в коде в WordPress используются функции локализации. Начать изучение можно [отсюда](https://wp-kama.ru/function/__).

Далее надо создать перевод строк в вашем текстовом домене, используя poedit или плагин LocoTranslate.

При переключении языка перевод будет выполнен автоматически.